# Can't save 3 level deeply from controller

Tags: php, cakephp, database-design, model, cakephp-2.0

I have the follow data, controller and model, which I need to save all together. `Foo` is saved and then `Bar`, but `deep` options seens not work when save `Baz`.

**Data**

```
array(
    'Foo' => array(
        'field1' => 'data',
        'field2' => 'data'
    ),
    'Bar' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'field1' => 'data',
            'field2' => 'data',
            'Baz' => array(
                'field1' => 'data'
            )
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'field1' => 'data',
            'field2' => 'data',
            'Baz' => array(
                'field1' => 'data'
            )
        )
        [...]
    )
)
```

**Controller**

```
$this->Bar->Foo->saveAll($data, array('deep', true));
```

**Model**

```
Bar belongsTo Foo
Foo hasMany Bar
Bar hasOne Baz
Baz belongsTo Bar
```

**Database fk**

```
Foo
Bar.foo_id
Baz.bar_id
```

`getDatasource()->getLog()` message says that can't save because of foreign key. Obviously `Baz` can't get fk from saved `Bar`.

I really can't find what is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Hierarchically seen it should be `$this->Foo->Bar->saveAll($data, array('deep', true));` and 'ddep' is either a typo here or should be changed to 'deep'. If your model is fine, CakePHP should safe the data correctly.

In the safe request there is indeed no direct relationship between Foo and Baz, hence the fk complaint. Or you've made a foreign key on SQL level what is very unlikely.

Comment: `ddep` is a typo only here ;D

Comment: I need to create `Foo` first to use fK inside `Bar` (`Bar.foo_id`), so, can't invert order of save.

Comment: Weel, I triple checked my model, and seens that one fk is named wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seens tha one of `HasOne`'s relation have a fk wrong named. **SOLVED!**